# How to setup an AWS amplify public API with key in url GET params?

Tags: reactjs, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm struggling to find the relevant docs for setting up a public API with AWS Amplify for a SaaS project which would require users to create a "project" and then be given an API key. I'm pretty sure this is a pretty common use case as far as I'm aware. I'd like to be able to generate multiple API keys for a user and then allow them to call the api via:

https://mysubdomain.domain.com/generate?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&title=FooBar

Ideally I'd then create a lambda function which would check to see if the key provided is stored in a dynamodb table. Is this possible with the current state of the amplify cli?

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api#api-key-auth

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Kyle